# Books or resources for GPU architecture

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, architecture, gpu

While many good books deal with CPU architecture in detail, for instance, *Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach* by *Patterson et al.*, and also some books deal with the hardware/software interface (CPU and the Operating Systems), for instance, *Computer Organization and Design: The Hardware/Software Interface* by *Patterson et al.* and Operating System books like the *OSTEP* by *Remzi et al.*

The books mentioned above, quite nicely and in good depth, cover the CPU architecture, page tables (the hardware and software contract), context switching, etc. But I don't know any book which deals with the same for GPUs.

Recently I was reading a research paper *GPUvm: GPU Virtualization at the Hypervisor* by *Yusuke Suzuki et al.*, where the authors were mentioning about GPU page tables, GPU contexts, GPU channels, PCIe BARs, MMIO (how CPU communicates with the GPU using MMIO and when it uses DMA).

[image]

[image]

They also talk about Unified Memory, how it works (in detail at the hardware level), and how things go hand in hand with the GPU driver, for instance, the open-source driver for Nvidia GPUs (Nouveau).

I am very eager to know about the GPU architecture in detail. Especially the hardware/software interface, which explains the whys and hows I currently have in mind.

Any help shall be highly appreciated.